# why is there an author.php

Tags: author

Why is there an author.php file when the same information is in the single.php? I looked at the template hierarchy and one would think that if author.php wasn't present, the single.php would come into play but it doesn't. I would also think that if you styled the author.php then that would affect the author bio on the pages, but it doesn't. So I was thinking about just removing the author bio all together. Maybe make it a function and call it in my page. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates):

> ...when a viewer clicks on a link to a post author, by default he or she is taken to a page listing the posts from that particular author in chronological order, from newest posts at the top to oldest at the bottom.

In other words, the author template is used to show posts made by one person as well as their bio (if so configured). Whether or not to use it is up you, so go ahead and remove it if you want or if you are the only author.

Answer (score 4):

*Author.php* is part of the *Archive.php* hierarchy.

It goes:

`author-$nicename.php` → `author-$id` → `author.php` →`archive.php` → `index.php`

*Single.php* is what it's name suggests and is related to posts, custom posts and attachments.

[image]

Larger version: http://debugggg.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/lgk541.png